# Remove .php and id from URL and replace with slash

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have tried lots of URL rewrite rules in *.htaccess* but I am stuck now. I have to change this URL:

```
    products.php?id=31
```

to

```
    products/31
```

I have used:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    # Turn mod_rewrite on
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    ## don't touch /forum URIs
    RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+products(?:\.php)?\?id=([0-9]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ products/%1? [R,L]

    RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/?$ products.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

    ## hide .php extension snippet
    # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

    # To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Using this I get the following result:

```
  products/31
```

But all images and CSS not displaying. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using relative URLs to your images / CSS files?

Comment: You have lots of rewrite rules that look like they should do the same thing.  Figure out which one is the one that is actually working.   I suspect you only need the forum rewrite rule and this one: `RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/?$ products.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]`   The duplicate rules should be removed so you can understand what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.php [NC]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^products/$ products.php?id=31 [L]
```

This code working fine for me.
For more details:
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html

Answer (score 1):

about the images and CSS not displaying;
If your URL gets rewritten to something like products/31
keep in mind that relative links inside the html are now relative
to products/ even though the php script itself sits in the root.
Because the html gets interpreted by the browser and the browser thinks
you are in the products/ folder.
You can use absolute urls (starting with http://hostname/ or just relative to root, thus starting with /) or have them rewritten too.